# Auto submit form every time when someone selects file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with only one file input and I want to auto submit the form every time when someone selects file. Now I use this code:

```
$(function(){
    $("#fil1").change(function(){
        $("#form1").submit();
    });
});
```

but it works only for the first selection. When I select some other file the form is't submitted again! It seems the change function is called only for the first time! Can anyone help? I use jquery...

Comment: Could you post the html that goes with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of jQuery are you using?  I just tried the code below and it worked multiple times.  Also wonder if it's your browser.  I tried Chrome and IE 8.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>index.html</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
alert('hit');
$(function(){
    $("#fil1").change(function(){
        $("#form1").submit();
    });
});
</script> 

</head>

<body> 

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
  <label for="fileField"></label>
  <input type="file" name="fileField" id="fil1">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

hope this helps...